# Size of Rdata file compared to csv

Tags: r, csv, rdata

The size of my .Rdata file is 92 MB.

However, the original csv-file is around 3 GB. I included it with the usual `read.csv()`

How can that be?

Comment: Could you tell us what the original csv looks like?

Comment: Binary vs. ASCII.   Assuming, that is, you've verified the contents of your `.Rdata` file and that your OS has updated file sizes correctly.

Comment: Also, .Rdata files are compressed by default.

Comment: 12417576 lines 14 columns, 3 dates, postcodes and a few columns with a handful of factors. Sounds very compressible, but still impressive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments already hinted at what is going on.  But this is so straightforward, let us do an example:

```
R> X <- 1:1e5   # data, no repeats
R> save(X, file="/tmp/foo.RData")
R> write.csv(X, file="/tmp/foo.csv")
R> system("ls -l /tmp/foo*")
-rw-r--r-- 1 x y 1377797 Jun  4 09:11 /tmp/foo.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 x y  212397 Jun  4 09:11 /tmp/foo.RData
```

Now with data that repeats:

```
R> X <- rep(1,1e5)   # data, lots of repeats
R> write.csv(X, file="/tmp/bar.csv")
R> save(X, file="/tmp/bar.RData")
R> system("ls -lh /tmp/bar*")
-rw-r--r-- 1 x y 966K Jun  4 09:12 /tmp/bar.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 x y 1.3K Jun  4 09:12 /tmp/bar.RData
R>
```

So we are getting ratios of 6.5 to 743 depending on how well this compresses.  And that is before we make the csv more "expensive" by forcing several decimals to be printed...

Comment: Gets even better with `rep(TRUE,1e5)`